# How to Properly forward a message from another user's channel into a group?

Tags: api, message, telegram, channel, forward

i would like to know how can i forward a message from a given channel id with the message number ( like when you copy the message link from inside the telegram itself) to a given group join link using messages.forwardMessage from telegram API funtion?

i.e: this is my join link of the destination:
https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAAlw6NYyLMlMES5hbw

and this is the message which should be forwarded to that above link:
https://t.me/kjdfvbjkdfbvkj/3

Thank you 
( esp to @apadana )

Comment: @apadana Ok, im waiting for you, Thanks

Comment: there are some details involving for forwarding from user/groups/supergroup/channels to users/groups/supergroups/channels. Which one are you looking to do? Public Channel to group (and possibly supergroup)?

Comment: Also have you done the joining part before sending a message? or you need help also with joining a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to forward from a group (not supergroup) to a channel. If you are looking for something else please comment.

```
#testChannel
source_chat_id=12345 
source_access_hash=1234567890
source_chat = InputPeerChannel(source_chat_id, source_access_hash)

#testGroup: 
dest_chat_id = 123456

# chat = InputPeerChannel(chat_id, access_hash)


total_count, messages, senders = client.get_message_history(
                        source_chat, limit=10)

msg = messages[0]    

dest_chat = InputPeerChat(dest_chat_id)
result = client.invoke(ForwardMessagesRequest(from_peer=source_chat, id=[msg.id], random_id=[generate_random_long()], to_peer=dest_chat))
```

Comment: @Burzum could you please run this for loop and post the result? for msg in reversed(messages):
    print ("msg:", msg.id, msg). 
my guess is that you might be forwarding a non message. You may also try to remove the for loop for forwardmessage and just try with one id that you know is a message.

Comment: @Burzum Also please note I changed my answer slightly to use ForwardMessagesRequest instead of ForwardMessageRequest (no s). There seems to be a bug with ForwardMessageRequest which is not in the Messages version. Also with the Messages version, you don't need to make the call several times. You can pass multiple messages in the list of ids.

Comment: @Burzum For supergroups you need to treat them like channels. So instead of InputPeerChat use InputPeerChannel which also needs an access_hash.

Comment: i think i got it, how can i determine if the given join link is a supergroup or a group?

Comment: i got this: `telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.ChatIdInvalidError: (ChatIdInvalidError(...), 'Invalid object ID for a chat. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for chats (not channels/megagroups) or otherwise look for a different one more suited\\nAn example working with a megagroup and AddChatUserRequest, it will fail because megagroups are channels. Use InviteToChannelRequest instead')`